# hibernate error when deploying application in wildfly

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly, cglib

I have an ear that works perfectly in Jbos7.1 server but in wildfly ther is an error when i deploy it:

> [0m[31m14:33:12,077 ERROR
>   [com.rcibanque.framework.persistance.hibernate.HibernateUtil]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 119) Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V  at
>   net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
>     at
>   net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
>     at
>   net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
>     at
>   net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
>     at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
>     at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)     at
>   net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)  at
>   net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)  at
>   net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)    at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
>     at
>   com.rcibanque.framework.persistance.hibernate.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:45)
>     at
>   com.rcibanque.framework.persistance.hibernate.HibernateTransaction.begin(HibernateTransaction.java:62)
>     at
>   com.rcibanque.common.application.ReferencesService.loadReferences(ReferencesService.java:62)
>     at com.rcibanque.common.session.InitServlet.init(InitServlet.java:94)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

can any one help me please? 
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you have an incompatibility between the version of ASM required by Hibernate  and the one provided by Wildfly. Can you post a list with all jar dependencies?

Comment: Thank's, but i do not use Spring

Comment: Sorry, I updated the comment.

Comment: i verified that the asm of the wildfly is the same of jboss7

Comment: I would not be so sure.

Comment: please list the jars which are in the lib folder of the ear.